# Sitecore 9.01 Azure PaaS XP Scaled XP The certificate was not found

Tags: azure, xconnect, paas

I have deployed our Sitecore 9 application to an Azure Scaled PaaS XP environment.

i have used the marketplace and selected a 9.01 infrastructure.

Our automated deployment has succeeded and our code deployed to both the CM and CD instances. on the CM i can log into Sitecore, run unicorn and can preview the pages.

the problem is when i try and view the site from the root domain i get the error below...

> The certificate was not found.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The certificate was not found.]
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier.Process(HttpClientHandler
>   handler) +276
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.CreateRequestHandler()
>   +182    Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.CreateClient() +56

the ARM templates from the marketplace have produced 3 instaced for xConnect, these are...

1. xc-collect
2. xc-refdata
3. xc-search

we have a step on our GULP file that will deploy DLLs, XML and JSON to XConnect and i am yet to do this on our live environment but im convinced this error is not related.

any help is most appreciated.

JGilmartin

Comment: Have you checked the thumbprints in your ConnectionString? it should be the same with the connection string in CM/CD and the xc- sites?

Comment: @JovitMayo - yes all the thumbprints are identical on all connection strings on all App Services. i have a ticket open with sitecore, ill post the solution once its resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error occurred for 2 reasons...

1
ensure in your web config for the instance your working on (CM, CD) you have thr following attribute `<add key="AllowInvalidClientCertificates" value="true"/>`

2
in Azure make sure that in the App Settings you have for **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** is set to a star -> *

once this is done, restart your app services and it will begin working

Answer (score 0):

In your ARM template installation script, have you tried something as shown below. This worked for us without any issues.

```
$CertificateFile = "Path to your .p12 file"
$Parameters = @{
"authCertificateBlob" = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($CertificateFile))
}
Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment -Name $DeploymentId -location $Location -ArmTemplatePath $SCARMTemplate -ArmParametersPath $ParamFile -LicenseXmlPath $LicenseFile -SetKeyValue $Parameters
```

Comment: for this deployment rather than using ARM templates, Ive used the Azure Sitecore Marketplace Installation wizard for 9.01